# Why is Mariamman sometimes depicted as having red skin?

Tags: devi, goddess, body, color

[Mariamman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariamman) is a fertility goddess primarily worshipped in Southern India. My family in Coimbatore lives near [one of her temples](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sri+muthu+mariyamman+kovil/@11.0150304,76.9603007,3a,75y,87.01h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1suzvq0S8RUZgPkj-8-804ew!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3Duzvq0S8RUZgPkj-8-804ew%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D87.00817%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x3ba8590ee2b3777d:0xb3b10235f408bf9b!2sSree+Sastha%E2%80%99s+Sweets+%26+Caterers!8m2!3d11.0139585!4d76.9595316!16s%2Fg%2F11h285t2kh!3m6!1s0x3ba859a1918a06c9:0x76ed523dac704b7f!8m2!3d11.0151555!4d76.9604692!10e5!16s%2Fg%2F11qbdvcryg), and the last time I visited, I noticed that they'd changed the Murti. The old one had been painted dark red; the new one is simpler and colorless. Looking up some pictures, most depictions of Mariamman show her as having a traditional skin color, about the same as most other female goddesses.

However, there were some images I was able to find that showed her as having red skin:

| ([Source](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/A_1993-0806-0-78)) | ([Source](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fsweetnothingsinlife.files.wordpress.com%2F2018%2F05%2Fthandu-mariamman.jpg%3Fw%3D714&tbnid=02M4BwZmiIBkgM&vet=12ahUKEwjnlY-jjYL_AhUiPt4AHSrmAwMQMygCegUIARC4AQ..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fsweetnothingsinlife.wordpress.com%2F2018%2F05%2F17%2F430-thandu-mariamman-temple-coimbatore%2F&docid=3anexaIAIBSAeM&w=188&h=268&q=mariamman%20kovil%20coimbatore&ved=2ahUKEwjnlY-jjYL_AhUiPt4AHSrmAwMQMygCegUIARC4AQ&safe=active&ssui=on)) | ([Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9382565884)) | ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariamman)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: row] | [image] | [image] |

The Wikipedia article for her says that she is "usually pictured as a beautiful young woman with a red-hued face," so I know it's been noted elsewhere before, but I can't find any clue as to the origin of this depiction. (The Wikipedia page doesn't provide any reference for that particular statement.)

So, is there any explanation anywhere as to why Mariamman has red skin? And is it merely her face that is to be red, or is it the entirety of her body? (Answers from scripture/Indologists/books are all ok)